# plot multiple figures interactively with split.screen and hold one constant

Tags: r, graphics, interactive

I am using R to plot a multifgure image with interactive capability in one of them.  I'm using `split.screen` to do this (as I tried unsuccesfuly to do it right with `par()` and base R graphics.

My goal is to hold the display of each `screen(1)` `j`th plot, while the `screen(2)` plot figure updates interactively `k` times..
But even though I set erase = `FALSE` or `TRUE`, each time it iterates through the subloop, the first plot is cleared and displays a blank image. Any ideas on how to hold the first plot image, each time the sub loop, `k` updates its graphics?

```
split.screen(figs=c(1,2),erase=TRUE)
for(j in 1:5){
    screen(1)
    plot(rnorm(3))
    screen(2)
for(k in 1:5){

    plot(rnorm(3))
    par(ask=TRUE)
             }
}
```

---

- update from help.

These functions are totally incompatible with the other mechanisms for arranging plots on a device: `par(mfrow), par(mfcol)'`and`'layout()`.

I guess that explains the `par(ask=TRUE)`. I'm still interested if anyone can do this using `par()` and base graphics functions.

I couldn't find any `par()` variables that would explicitly specify one of the two screens to plot on at any step, while allowing `par(ask=T)` to update in a subloop, which is what `split.screen()` was able to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give `Hmisc::subplot` a try:

```
## draw first plot
par(mfcol=c(1,2), xpd=NA)
plot(rnorm(3))
plot(1,1) # dummy plot

## update subplot k times
for(k in 1:5) { 
  rect(grconvertX(par("fin")[1], from="inches"),
       grconvertY(0, from="inches"),
       grconvertX(par("fin")[1]*2, from="inches"),
       grconvertY(par("fin")[2], from="inches"), col="white", border=NA)  ## cover-up
  subplot( plot(rnorm(3)), 1, 1, size=par("pin") )  
  readline("Hit <Return> to see next plot: ")
}
```

Comment: nice. but it still ignores the par(ask=TRUE), which if I insert is overridden. Same problem I had with par(mfg) approach.

Comment: I missed that detail. Too bad subplot ignores ask. Would a workaround using `readline` work for you? (see edit above)

Comment: not bad at all. I upvoted and will wait to see if anyone can do it in basic graphics, but if I can't get any other results, I'll close vote it, as it solves the problem. thank you. PS. Did you get that out of a graphics book I could buy, or just reading packages.

Comment: Thanks for the +1! I discovered readline when I was editing an interactive function written by a colleague

Answer (score 0):

Adding a `flush.console()` and `Sys.sleep()` should do it.

```
split.screen(figs=c(1,2),erase=TRUE)
for(j in 1:5){
  screen(1)
  plot(rnorm(3))
  flush.console()
  Sys.sleep(0.5)
  for(k in 1:5){
    screen(2)
    plot(rnorm(3))
    par(ask=TRUE)
    flush.console()
    Sys.sleep(0.5)
  }
}
```

That will still suppress the `par(ask=TRUE)` as per the warnings, but it should prevent the first plot going blank whilst the second iterates.